# Why docker run saying Unknown operand whilst same shell script runs perfectly in ubuntu machine

Tags: docker, unix, jq, jsonpath

I am trying to execute a `./login.sh` as a part of `docker run` now when i run the `./login.sh` in ubuntu machine i see success response but when i create a docker image i see output as `sh: abc: unknown operand “invalid url”`

Here is contents of `./login.sh`

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # Black Box Tester!


content=$(curl  --location --request POST "https://api.platform.abc.com. 
/auth/oauth/token" --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded' \
 --header 'Authorization: Basic V0zSA==' --data-raw 'grant_type=password&
username=test@example.com&password=123456'| jq -r '.domain_id' )
if [ $content = abc ]
     then
          echo “Valid Login Token”
else
          echo “invalid url”
fi
```

and here is contents of docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl   \
    && apt-get -y install jq


FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add curl jq


WORKDIR /opt


ADD login.sh /opt

RUN pwd  \
   && find /opt



CMD ["./login.sh"]
```

When same `./login.sh` i execute normally in Ubuntu machine i get successful output as

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-248:~$ ./login.sh 
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time    
  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2034  100  1958  100    76   9458    367 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  
9873
“Valid Login Token”
```

Here is output of `sudo docker run lots/loginimage`

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-248:~$ sudo docker run lots/loginimage
 ./login.sh: line 6: jq: not found
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time       
 Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 92  2034   92  1807  100    76   7199    302 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--      
7501
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1024)
sh: abc: unknown operand
“invalid url”
```

Can some one let me know why the login script which is simply a curl command runs sucessfully in ubuntu machine but same login script shows else condition in docker run?

Also i have included a code in docker file to download and install Json path `jq` but why image still says `./login.sh: line 6: jq: not found`??

your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Because you downloaded it into `/opt` not into on of the folders in `PATH`

Comment: Can you test this piece of code within a container and outside of it? `if [ = abc ]; then echo “Valid Login Token”; else  echo “invalid url”; fi`? Does it also give you a "unknown operand" error? If that's the case, then you can probably guess that `$content` is evaluated to empty string, and the `if` statement becomes `if [ = abc]` which gives you the error that you are seeing.

Comment: @CarolynCordeiro: Also I suggest to remove the _bash_ tag from your question, because your script does not use bash, and the question is not related to bash in any other way.

Comment: @KamilCuk how can i download it in PATH ?

Comment: But why would you download it? Just install it from repo. `apt-get install jq`. Usually custom administrator tools are placed in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: @KamilCuk Updated the docker file in question with apt-get -y install jq but still get jq not found :(

Comment: @KamilCuk added jq in apk add as well still docker run says jq not found

Comment: Did you build your image after changing the Dockerfile? Please include the build output. Also the first `FROM` section is useless, you're creating a multi-stage build and never doing anything with the first stage.

Answer (score 0):

While creating docker you need to install jq `sudo apt-get install jq`

Comment: Updated the docker file in question with apt-get -y install jq but still get jq not found :(

Comment: added added jq in apk add as well still docker run says jq not found

Comment: One possibility is your env is not loaded. Try to run command using sudo.

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/matryer/bitbar/issues/415